# ELM327 Bluetooth OBD-II adapter using Eric Smekens node-bluetooth-obd

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth

Iam getting the following error ReferenceError: require is not defined in browser when i try to run Eric Smekens node-bluetooth-obd test.js

when adding require.js the following error has been seen "error: Module name "../lib/obd.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded"

I have tested this on firefox and IE edge any suggestions regarding these errors please.

i am just running them to understand the code though it wont gets execute here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module should be used in Node.js environment, not in browser environment.

Install Node.js, then in command-line create a `package.json` file with `npm init`, install the module `npm install --save bluetooth-obd` and then use it in your script like this `require('bluetooth-obd')`. To run the script, type `node myscript.js`.